# N: Skipping acquire of configured file on repository 'https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal InRelease' doesn't supp arch 'i386'

Tags: linux, x86, mono, ubuntu-20.04, apt

I am trying to install **mono** or **mono-complete** on Ubuntu 20.04. I have got instruction to install or setup on Ubuntu,

these are

```
$ sudo apt install dirmngr gnupg apt-transport-https ca-certificates software-properties-common
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
$ sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal main'
```

Before, installing the **mono-complete**

```
$ sudo apt install mono-complete
```

I wanted to call the latest repository or packages available from server, for that I tried to update **apt** package

```
$ sudo apt update
```

While updating I got the following error

```
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

what is problem? how to resolved this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, on Ubuntu 20.04, changed a line in **/etc/apt/sources.list** from

```
deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal main
```

to

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal main
```